# Is it valid to use newer toolchain for application build?

Tags: arm, glibc, yocto, toolchain, buildroot

Currently we build our application with same toolchain as the toolchain used for building root filesystem.

Is it valid to build application with a newer toolchain, or will it result in any mismatches when running on the target filesystem ?

**EDIT**:

I want to add sanitize checking for application. Unfortunately arm-linux-gnueabihf version 4.8 does not support it yet. So I want to build my application with the same linaro toolchain for same architecture, just more updated (version 6.4 instead of 4.8)

Comment: Root file system will consist of the dynamic libraries so if you compile your application using different tool-chain there may be a possibility of format mismatch and you may get an `exec: format error` when you try to execute the binary.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question, I use same architecture just update from gcc 4.8 to gcc 6.4.

Comment: Is it a C or C++ application?

Comment: It's a C and C++ application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you require ABI compatibility between your old libraries and your recompiled application. The C ABI is much simpler as the C++ ABI. You won't have problems with the C parts.

For the C++ parts you might have to select the right ABI version via g++ -fabi-version.

For the C ABI, it is a matter of ABI compatibility between the libc versions used. glibc (which is the one used by the Linaro toolchain) is generally safe.